# Meaning of a proc name ending with ::

Tags: tcl

In the tk code base I found the construct:

```
proc ::tk::dialog::file::chooseDir:: {args} {
```

Normally I would expect the procedure name after the last set of `::` but here it is empty. Is this some sort of constructor in a namespace?
(Might look like a trivial question but I'm not a tcl programmer and need to know it to, automatically, generate some documentation.

Some more of the code (maybe gives some background, it is the beginning of the file)

```
namespace eval ::tk::dialog {}
namespace eval ::tk::dialog::file {}

namespace eval ::tk::dialog::file::chooseDir {
    namespace import -force ::tk::msgcat::*
}

proc ::tk::dialog::file::chooseDir:: {args} {
    variable ::tk::Priv
    set dataName __tk_choosedir
    upvar ::tk::dialog::file::$dataName data
    Config $dataName $args
    ...
```

Comment: This is part of Tk's implementation. You probably shouldn't generate much documentation for it in the first place (the supported API is listed on https://www.tcl-lang.org/man)

Comment: @DonalFellows I know that it is not specifically for tk, but as it is in a general documentation package (doxygen, has some limited support for tcl) and I discovered the problem with th I used this as an example to get things clearified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Normally I would expect the procedure name after the last set of ::
>   but here it is empty

The empty string is a valid name for a procedure in Tcl (as it for variables).

```
% namespace eval ::tk::dialog::file::chooseDir {}
% proc ::tk::dialog::file::chooseDir:: {args} { return "called!" }
% ::tk::dialog::file::chooseDir::
called!
% namespace eval ::tk::dialog::file::chooseDir { "" }
called!
% info procs ::tk::dialog::file::chooseDir::*
::tk::dialog::file::chooseDir::
```

I don't know the history behind these Tk internals, but a procedure named using the empty string might be the main procedure for the same-named namespace `chooseDir` (as a kind of naming convention), rather than just duplicating the name: `proc ::tk::dialog::file::chooseDir::chooseDir {args} {;}`. Or, it is because the entire directory-picking functionality is [auto_load](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/auto%5Fload)ed, which requires a proc (command) name rather than a namespace name?

> automatically, generate some documentation.

Maybe, when harvesting a Tcl interpreter for pieces to document, take the containing namespace name `chooseDir` as the documented name of such a procedure?

Comment: FWIW, `::tk::dialog::file::chooseDir::` is intimately linked to  [tk_chooseDirectory](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tk_chooseDirectory).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I think with this information I can work with it.

Comment: For commands, there's not really a lot of benefit to using these weird names. There also isn't any special convention outside the deep guts of part of Tk. Variables with the empty name work very well *if they are arrays* as then you can do `set (elem) ...` and `$(elem)`.

Comment: Also, sqlite3 doesn't like an empty array name for the result set holder name. That seems like a bug...